# Read a filename from json and include it by jekyll

Tags: json, html, jekyll

Let you assume that I have this json file:

```
{
    "components":[
        {
                "id" : "brandbar",
                "name" : "brandbar.html",
                "type":"navbar",
                "description":"Bar with the brand",
                "status": "draft"
        },
        {       
                "id":"topbar",
                "type":"navbar",
                "component":"Best brand",
                "description":"Chart with Date"
        }]
}
```

Now, I would like to have a loop on this json to retrieve the filenames.

```
{% for entry in site.data.component.components %}
                <div class="col-md-12">
                     {% include {{ entry.name }} %}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that I can't use {{ entry.name }} in my include statement.

is there a way to achieve this goal ?
I don't want to loop directly in my folder... I would like to have a main file where I will fill in every important attribute about the components.

Comment: have you seen https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/176 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to indent you json with spaces instead of tabs.

This might do the trick :

```
{"components":[
    {
        "id" : "brandbar",
        "name" : "brandbar.html",
        "type":"navbar",
        "description":"Bar with the brand",
        "status": "draft"
    },
    {       
        "id":"topbar",
        "type":"navbar",
        "component":"Best brand",
        "description":"Chart with Date"
    }
]}
```

Except that topbar has no name propriety, and this can cause an error.